# Automatically save the last open Excel file date

Tags: excel, vba

Currently I have a code that allows me to produce the current date when I run the code. However, I would like date automatically to be updated when it is closed so then when I open it the next time, I would know when was the date last opened. Below is the code that I have currently:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

Dim Home As Worksheet
Set Home = Worksheets("Program Status Summary")
Home.Range("A1").Value = Format(Now(), "dd/mmm/yyyy")

End Sub
```

Comment: Use the "Workbook_BeforeClose" event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To follow up on my comment: Simply add an event handler for `Workbook_BeforeClose` to the workbook object of the VBA project.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim Home As Worksheet
    Set Home = Worksheets("Program Status Summary")
    Home.Range("A1").Value = Format(Now(), "dd/mmm/yyyy")
End Sub
```

You'll probably want to save the changes as well in order to prevent a "save changes" prompt.

**Update**: The following example automatically saves changes if the workbook was saved before the code made changes. This is necessary to avoid saving changes that the user didn't intend.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim wasSaved As Boolean
    wasSaved = ThisWorkbook.saved

    Dim Home As Worksheet
    Set Home = Worksheets("Program Status Summary")
    Home.Range("A1").Value = Format(Now(), "dd/mmm/yyyy")

    If wasSaved Then ThisWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi should i put the code in the modules or workbook?

Comment: In the workbook. The ThisWorkbook object to be exact.

Comment: I tried putting in the workbook but when i try to run it, there is a pop up asking me to choose macro name for me to run

Comment: That's because it's an event handler that receives its "Cancel" parameter when the event is fired. The code should run when you close the workbook, and you can use the parameter to cancel the closing if you will.

If you want to test the code, add it to a Sub with no parameters :-) That sub can then be called from the Workbook_BeforeClose event handler.

Comment: Alright i understand now. Thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: Hi i forgot to mention that everytime i try to close the excel file, it will keep prompting for any changes to be save even after i have click on the "save" icon. May i know why does the prompt keep appearing when i want to close the excel file?

Comment: It appears because the code does indeed perform a change. In order to not *force* a save, you'd need to store whether the current workbook was saved previously by storing ThisWorkbook.Saved in a boolean variable in the first line of the code. Then in the last line of the code, if the boolean variable is true, you should call ThisWorkbook.Save as the other answer mentions.

Comment: Sorry i don't really understand what you trying to say. Do you mean before the  Private Sub i would need to declare the ThisWorkbook.Save as a boolean?

Comment: Inside the sub. The "save changes" confirmation dialog appears because the code performs changes. Since the user might not have saved their changes, you can't just go ahead and call ThisWorkbook.Save at the end of the Sub, because you might save something the user didn't want to. So in order to produce the desired behaviour for the user, you should only call ThisWorkbook.Save if ThisWorkbook.Saved was true before you made the changes in code - at the start of the Sub.

Comment: If it still doesn't make sense to you, I'll update my answer to handle the new requirements later or tomorrow.

Comment: Can you show the updated answer? maybe from there i would understand. Sorry for the trouble

Answer (score 2):

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Range("A1") = Date
    ThisWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

This would do it.
The "ThisWorkbook.save" part saves the workbook after adding with the current date

Comment: Do note that the Range method without an explicit sheet object qualifier will refer to the active sheet, which is not desired in this case. Link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Thank you for your help! your method did help too! :)

Comment: Glad to Help :) - As @DanL note, you can also add  "Thisworkbook.sheets("sheet1").Range("A1") = Date" to specify the sheet.

Comment: I just wanted to make it as simple as possible :)